# Img align:left causes text overflow in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fckeditor

I'm having an issue with text overflowing within a column when an inline image is aligned left or right. Its hard to describe so I created an example page at http://alaskalegion.com/dev/test.php

This only occurs in IE6 and IE7. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

I'm using fckeditor on the backend which is generating these.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem in ie7 with 

.news-entry p {
 overflow: hidden; 
 }

The problem still occurs in ie6 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the `p` tag wraps around the image so that other paragraphs are above and below it. I can´t test it right now, but I usually use `overflow:hidden` on the surrounding block (the paragraph) and I think for IE you need something like `zoom:1`.

**By the way**, can´t you get rid of the inline 'align:left' and replace it by css in an external style sheet like:

```
#center-column p img {
    float: none;       // if still necessary...
}
#wide_column p img {     // I don´t know what the id of the wide column is...
    float: left;
}
```

(I don´t know if you need the `p` selector, I'm only trying to target the right images without seeing your code)

Comment: I know its caused by the align="left". The issue is that this content appears on this page in a single column format and it also appears in a full page where the align="left" is required obviously for layout purposes. Is there any css trickery to keep the align="left" but not cause this bug.

Comment: Sorry, I removed something from my original answer and now it doesn´t answer you question anymore... I´ll add it back / change the answer so that it makes sense.

Comment: Sweet that worked. Removing the float in an ie6 only stylesheet cleared away that problem and the layout still looks good.